# 2 Integrating factors for a ODE 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Proof that:
If $u$ and $v$ are two integrating factors for the equation $Mdx+Ndy=0$ where $M=M(x,y)$ and $ N=N(x,y)$,
then the general solution is $u=cv$ where $c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  It might be helpful to show what you have tried, where you are stuck.  Maybe define what you mean by 'integral factor.'

Comment: Can you give the references from which you got this problem? @Henry Fernando